# What is the best way to verify the SSL configuration of my web server?

Tags: tls, webserver, configuration

How do I ensure I have my SSL configuration setup securely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SSL Labs rocks for verifying all the nuances of a proper SSL setup - just put your domain name in and hit submit:

https://www.ssllabs.com/

Answer (score 5):

(shameless advertisement)

There are various Web-based services which can test your server (e.g. SSL Labs) but this works only if your server is generically accessible from the Internet. If you want to test a server for which this is not true, you need a tool that you can run from a desktop system. I [wrote one](http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) (opensource, free). Remember, though, that such a tool can never guarantee that your server is "secure"; that's way too vague an assertion. SSL test tools (and this includes SSL Labs and its ilk) can "only" point out some things which look fishy; they cannot claim exhaustivity, and they cover only the SSL level.